# VBA 2D Array Split using multiple delimiter

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, 2d, delimiter

Currently I'm trying to read a break my file down into a 2 column table using different delimiter, for example:

```
-5 Name1, +7 Octopus, -6 Name22, +5 Horse, -7 Name100, +3 Owl
```

My end result should be a 2 column table like:

Name1 Octopus
Name22 Horse
Name100 Owl

So far my code is rather simplistic:

```
Sub SplitText()

Dim TextString As String, WArray() As String, Counter As Integer, Strng As String

    TextSring = Range("A1").Value
    WArray() = Split(TextString, ",")

    For Counter = LBound(WArray) To UBound(WArray)

        Strng = WArray(Counter)
        Cells(Counter + 2, 1).Value = Trim(Strng)

    NextCounter

End Sub
```

Your help is very much needed, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This below code works with the string you have provided. I hope it will be OK with your real data. See comments for explanations.

```
Sub SplitText()
Dim s As String
Dim v
Dim i As Long, j As Long


s = "-5 Name1, +7 Octopus, -6 Name22, +5 Horse, -7 Name100, +3 Owl"

'let's remove space, pluses and minuses
s = Replace(Replace(Replace(s, " ", ""), "+", ""), "-", "")

'and cut by commas
v = Split(s, ",")

For i = 0 To UBound(v)
    If InStr(v(i), "Name") Then
        'remove numbers before names
        v(i) = "Name" & Split(v(i), "Name")(1)
    Else
        For j = 48 To 57
            'remove figures in animals
            v(i) = Replace(v(i), ChrW(j), "")
        Next j
    End If
Next i

For i = 0 To UBound(v) Step 2
    'see the results
    Debug.Print v(i) & " " & v(i + 1)
Next i
End Sub
```